# how to select dropdownlist value and display in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have an MVC3 web application. On `index.cshtml` I have two dropdown lists. When I select from those lists I need to click on a `next` button and I want to display the selected values. How can i do this?

*homecontroller.cs*

```
DataRepository objRepository = new DataRepository();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel objViewModel = new ViewModel();
    objViewModel.ID = objRepository.GetPricingSecurityID();
    objViewModel.ddlId = objRepository.GetCUSIP();
    return View(objViewModel);
}
```

*ViewModel.cs*

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //DDL ID
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PricingSecurityID")]
    public List<SelectListItem> ddlId { get; set; }

    //DropDownList Values
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a PricingSecurityID")]
    public List<SelectListItem> ID { get; set; }
}
```

*index.cshtml*

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("Pricing SecurityID")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID,
        new SelectList(Model.ID, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- Select category --"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.Label("CUSIP ID")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ddlId,
        new SelectList(Model.ddlId, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- Select category --"
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ddlId)
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</p>
```

How can I display selected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requirement is to build some kind of wizard, you need a way of maintaining state between steps.

ViewBag is no good for this because you should be following the PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern for each wizard step.

TempData would work for navigating forward between steps but will fall over if the user goes back or navigates to a step directly.

You therefore need something with a longer lifetime. The ASP.NET Session object or a database are both good candidates for this.

Here's an example:

```
public class WizardController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        var session = GetWizardSession();

        if (session.Step1 == null)
        {
            session.Step1 = new Step1View
            {
                PricingSecurityIds = new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }),
                SomeOtherIds = new SelectList(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
            };
        }

        return View(session.Step1);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step1(Step1View cmd)
    {
        var session = GetWizardSession();

        // save the wizard state
        session.Step1.SelectedPricingSecurityId = cmd.SelectedPricingSecurityId;
        session.Step1.SelectedSomeOtherId = cmd.SelectedSomeOtherId;

        // now onto step 2
        session.Step2 = new Step2View
        {
            PricingSecurityId = cmd.SelectedPricingSecurityId,
            SomeOtherId = cmd.SelectedSomeOtherId,
            Name = "John Smith"
        };

        return RedirectToAction("step2");
    }

    public ActionResult Step2()
    {

        return View(GetWizardSession().Step2);
    }

    public WizardSession GetWizardSession()
    {
        var session = Session["wizardsession"];

        if (session == null)
        {
            session = new WizardSession();
            Session["wizardsession"] = session;
        }

        return session as WizardSession;
    }
}

public class Step1View
{
    public SelectList PricingSecurityIds { get; set; }
    public SelectList SomeOtherIds { get; set; }
    public int SelectedPricingSecurityId { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSomeOtherId { get; set; }
}

public class Step2View
{
    public int PricingSecurityId { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WizardSession
{
    public Step1View Step1 { get; set; }
    public Step2View Step2 { get; set; }
}
```

- In **Step1** we make a call to `GetWizardSession`. This returns an object from the ASP.NET `Session` that contains all of the information we have collected for each step in the wizard. In this example we simply store the ViewModel for each step (i.e. `session.Step1`).
- We check to see if Step1 exists in the session and create it if it doesn't. We then pass the Step1 model to our view.
- When the user submits the form we update the "Selected" values in `session.Step1`. This ensures that if the user navigates back to /step1, we "remember" their values. We then build the model for **Step2** and save it in the session.
- When we navigate to /step2 we assume that a model exists in the session (because they should have got here from step1) so we just return `return View(GetWizardSession().Step2);`

The views:

#### Step 1

```
@model MvcWizardDemo.Controllers.Step1View

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step1";
}

<h2>Step1</h2>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Step1View</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PricingSecurityIds)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedPricingSecurityId, Model.PricingSecurityIds)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PricingSecurityIds)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeOtherIds)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSomeOtherId, Model.SomeOtherIds)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeOtherIds)
            </div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Next" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

#### Step 2

```
@model MvcWizardDemo.Controllers.Step2View

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Step2";
}

<h2>Step2</h2>

Hi, @Model.Name you selected the following values in the previous step:

<p>
    <strong>Security Id:</strong> @Model.PricingSecurityId
</p>

<p>
    <strong>Some other Id:</strong> @Model.SomeOtherId
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work :

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel model)
{
    // put what you want to show

}
```

Comment: This would not work. You need to add additional properties to the POST model to store the selected values. As per my answer.